# Linear optimization problem became non-linear

Tags: linear-programming, pulp

I have been solving the following problem with Linear programming: We have several arrays of data, which all are a composition of around 4 base-arrays. We know the proportion of each base array, and try to figure out what the base-arrays are that lead to the smallest error.

As an example with 2 base arrays:

```
data1: 1 2 3 4 5; 1.0/0.0
data2: 3 3 3 3 3; 0.5/0.5
data3: 5 4 3 2 1; 0.0/1.0
```

With this input, we can deduce that base array 1 is `1 2 3 4 5` and base array 2 is `5 4 3 2 1`, as this assignment will lead to error 0.

In particular, we have 5 variables for array 1 we try to estimate, and 5 variables for array 2. Data2 will lead to the constraints:

```
posError1 >= 3 - arr_1_0 * 0.5 + arr_2_0 * 0.5
posError1 >= arr_1_0 * 0.5 + arr_2_0 * 0.5 - 3
posError2 >= 3 - arr_1_1 * 0.5 + arr_2_1 * 0.5
posError2 >= arr_1_1 * 0.5 + arr_2_1 * 0.5 - 3
posError3 >= 3 - arr_1_2 * 0.5 + arr_2_2 * 0.5
posError3 >= arr_1_2 * 0.5 + arr_2_2 * 0.5 - 3
posError4 >= 3 - arr_1_3 * 0.5 + arr_2_3 * 0.5
posError4 >= arr_1_3 * 0.5 + arr_2_3 * 0.5 - 3
posError5 >= 3 - arr_1_4 * 0.5 + arr_2_4 * 0.5
posError5 >= arr_1_4 * 0.5 + arr_2_4 * 0.5 - 3
```

At the end, we minimize `error` which is the sum of all `posErrorX`.

Usually each data array has around 100k entries, and we have around 10 data arrays and 4 base arrays.

This was solvable with a strong enough machine with pulp. However, now we are in a situation where we only know what percentage 2 of our base arrays are included at, so there is one more variable per data array we have to figure out. So we would have x/0.5-x/0.2/0.3 instead of knowing all 4 values. This isn't a huge change, except that we now have a non-linear problem. What is the best way to go about this?

I was not able to linearize this problem, is there a method that would be able to handle this problem in a reasonable time?

Comment: I'm struggling to follow the details of your new formulation. Could you please formulate it mathematically, making sure to clarify which parts of your formulation are data and which are decision variables?

Comment: Can you edit your post and explain more clearly what you mean by "we only know what percentage 2 of our base arrays are included at...."  I think I understand that you have 4 "base arrays" that are vectors of 100k unknown variables.  Are you saying that you know (for every array in the 10 data arrays what proportional contribution 2 of the unknown arrays accounts for?  That would be weird to know the proportional contribution of a vector of unknowns... ??